# ArrayList error:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 26, size is 26

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a small app which shows the current Gold and Silver Prices. I have attached small screen shot of the app. It has two action bar items refresh and settings . When I click on the refresh button I have to get the current update prices for gold . I do get the updated prices for some time but after some time it crashes with above error.

I am using JSOUP library to fetch the data from UOB bank.

http://s23.postimg.org/580ofx68b/UOBGoldand_Silver.jpg

The Error log :

```
2779-2779/com.example.coherendz.uobgoldandsilver E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 26, size is 26
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.example.coherendz.uobgoldandsilver.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:68)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:639)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4970)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4127)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am posting my code below:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.coherendz.uobgoldandsilver;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    String cadena;

    private final String siteUrl = "https://uniservices1.uobgroup.com/secure/online_rates/gold_and_silver_prices.jsp";

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private TextView txtResponse;
    private Document doc;
    ArrayList<String> arr_linkText= new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList names,currency,weight,Buy,Sell;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

        (new ParseURL()).execute(new String[]{siteUrl});

    }

    private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try

            {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(siteUrl).get();
                String title = doc.title();
                Log.i(TAG, title);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            names = Values(0);
            currency = Values(1);
            weight = Values(2);
            Buy =  Values(3);
            Sell = Values(4);

            for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
                for (Element row : table.select("tr.roll2,tr.roll1")) {
                    Elements column = row.select("td");
                    cadena = column.text();
                    cadena += "\n";
                    arr_linkText.add(cadena);
                    Log.i(TAG, cadena);
                }
            }

            return arr_linkText.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(arr_linkText,names,currency,weight,Buy,Sell,MainActivity.this);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu_settings; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Intent i = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
           startActivity(i);
        }

        else if(id == R.id.action_refresh){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Refresh Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            (new ParseURL()).execute(new String[]{siteUrl});
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private ArrayList Values(int i) {

        ArrayList Temparray = new ArrayList();

        for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr.roll2,tr.roll1")) {
                Elements column = row.select("td");
                cadena = column.get(i).text();
                cadena += "\n";
                Temparray.add(cadena);
                //Log.i(TAG, cadena);
            }
        }

        return Temparray;
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.coherendz.uobgoldandsilver;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    private ArrayList currency,weight,Buy,Sell;
    ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();


    public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList myList,ArrayList names,ArrayList currency,ArrayList weight,ArrayList Buy,ArrayList Sell, Context context) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.names = names;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.Buy = Buy;
        this.Sell = Sell;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MyViewHolder mViewHolder=null;


        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String name="",weig="",buy="",sell="";

        name = names.get(position).toString();
        weig = weight.get(position).toString();
        buy = Buy.get(position).toString();
        sell = Sell.get(position).toString();


        mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(name);
        mViewHolder.tvQty.setText(weig);
        mViewHolder.tvBuy.setText(buy);
        mViewHolder.tvSell.setText(sell);

        loadSavedPreferences();

        return convertView;
    }

    private void loadSavedPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences prefs;
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Checked Values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String Arbor = prefs.getString("Arbor", null);
        String Cast = prefs.getString("Cast", null);

        if(Arbor!=null&&Cast!=null){

            Log.i("SRI",Arbor);
            Log.i("Kanth",Cast);

        }
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle,tvQty,tvBuy,tvSell;

        MyViewHolder(View v){

          tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
          tvQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvQty);
          tvBuy = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvBuy);
          tvSell = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSell);

        }

    }
}
```

Any Suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: It would seem that the ArrayLists you're passing to the Adapter are not all the same size. You should check this when instantiating the Adapter.

Comment: Buy.get(position).toString(); may i see the implementation of get(int i) function?

Comment: @MikeM.Yes,they are of not same size.

Comment: Well, `names`, `weight`, `Buy`, and `Sell` need to be the same size as `myList`, going by how you've implemented the Adapter.

Comment: Just a suggestion: If properties are to be grouped, its better to create a class `YourClass` that binds your properties you want, and then create ArrayList of type `YourClass`

Comment: @Mike M: How can i make them of same size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list will give you `myList.size()` number of entries but you use `.get(position)` on `names` and `weight` as well in the adapters `getView()`.

**Solution 1:**
Check the lengths of your input in the constructor and throw a exception if the input argument `names` and `weight` are of less length than `myList`.

**Solution 2:**
Let `getCount()` return the shortest length of the arrays you use in the `getView()`

The moral of the story is *Never trust your inputs*

Comment: Solution 2 : Worked for me . Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @Srikanth86in Just a note: you never clear the `arr_linkText` ArrayList when you refresh, so it just keeps growing.

Comment: @Mike M: You are right. I had to clear the that array and your suggestion worked too.